# iOS app distribution issue

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, app-store-connect

I need to know if the name in "Distribution Certificate" is this "Seller" name (http://cl.ly/26371G2g3g0H2z1w3s2N), or this http://cl.ly/0S3t080b170Q152u1x03 or maybe is not displayed in iTunes?

It's important, because I would like this name of Distribution Certificate not to be displayed anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only name that will be displayed as the "Seller name" in the App Store ist the name you entered when enrolling to the iOS developer programm. Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enrollment.html) to prove my answer.

> ...
>   Your legal name will appear as the 'Seller Name' in the App Store.
>   ...

So it doesn't matter how your Distribution Certificate is named …

Comment: Unless he has an enterprise account and releases an app using a distribution provisioning file. Just for reference!

Comment: +1 But the screenshot is from the App Store and you're not abled to submit to the App Store with an enterprise account …

Comment: Correct, but mobile device management (MDM) software providers typically offer an appstore-like interface for enterprise apps, which will also use & display this information.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm afraid I don't get this... Basically I joined to the "iOS Developer Program" so I guess I can submit apps to the AppStore - and that's what I need. But I would like to know what name will be displayed on iTunes app page... this from Certificate or the one I put while were joining the program. Or maybe just the one from credit card? :)

Comment: It's the one you entered when you joined the porgram.